# Can one preset credentials for ServiceConnect["Twitter", "New"] to allow wolframscript headless use?

Tags: external-calls, social-media

Trying to run some wolframscript code from a server, is it possible to set `ServiceConnect` credentials in the environmental variables for example?

Comment: I am not sure about a way to store a connection as env. variable. But there is a was you can save a connection persistently and use that saved connection later in some other kernel session. e.g. ```ServiceConnect["Twitter", "New", SaveConnection -> True];twitter = First@ServiceConnections`SavedConnections["Twitter"]; twitter["UserData", "Username" -> "elonmusk"]``` should work.